# Factors governing the avoidance of contracted forms such as we're, I'm or didn't and wouldn't

Tags: grammar, contractions

I am looking for a comprehensive lists of the factors that govern the avoidance of contracted forms such as we're, I'm or didn't and wouldn't and so on.

So far I have found (personal impressions):

- Very formal communication

Comment: What are your sources? I see contracted forms often enough in business communication and I can see no link whatsoever between _memories_ and contracted forms.

Comment: I changed my question.

Comment: Laziness maybe :)

Comment: I still don't see the _memories_ link. Contracted forms are used _a lot_ in general.

Comment: Not between your two points. I simply don't see your second point at all. That is why I am asking you what your sources are. I am wondering where you got the idea that _memories_ matter _at all_. Contracted forms are also used when people talk about animals, about work, about their hobby or about books. They always use them _except_ in some cases. I think it is more interesting to look when contracted forms are _not_ used. (That last sentence is an example!)

Comment: oerkelens, that's an intelligent point, i wasn't aware of the fact that it would be better to ask when they are avoided. So I modified the question, thank you.

Comment: I wish you wouldn't have edited out your thoughts on when contractions should be used - I found it helpful in understanding what you were asking. Maybe include your thoughts on when they shouldn't be used?

Comment: Added an example, ColleenV. I still think asking the other way round, as suggested by oerkelens, makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I agree, I missed some of the comment.

Answer (score 3):

I think the basic rule is that you can always use contracted forms, *except* in some cases.

- In very formal texts, where it is very important that the reader does not “miss" the negation or interprets the wrong verb (*'s* can be read as *is* or *has*). I'm thinking about legal texts, contracts, and things like that.
- In situations where you want to *emphasize* the negation or the verb. As I said in the comments: “maybe you shouldn't ask when contracted forms are used, but when they are *not* used.” “He said he wouldn't be able to make it, but he just called: he *is* coming after all!”
- As a matter of style. I can imagine at least some style guides will tell you not to use any contracted forms (not only negations, but also affirmative verb contractions like he's, they're, I'm).
- For rhythmic purposes, in poetry or a song text. Then again, in those cases you are pretty much free to choose what sounds best anyway.

As ColleenV mentions in a comment, especially in case of contracted affirmative forms, we also do not use them at the end of a sentence: **I wondered if he was coming, but there he's!*. However, contracted negations are fine at the end of a sentence: *I thought was coming, but actually, he isn't*.

Comment: Also at the end of a sentence. "I asked where and she said there it's." "You might not do it, but they're"

Comment: @ColleenV: those are not contracted negations, but you are right. Although your second example, I would put as _you might not do it, but they'll_.

Comment: I didn't interpret the question as being only about negations, even though all of the examples were negations. I saw the problem in my example in the comment after my 5 minutes expired. I need to stop changing my mind about what I'm going to write mid-sentence :) I was trying to work in the homophone contractions somehow but I'm short on time.

Comment: @ColleenV: I took the liberty of including your point in my answer, thank you for mentioning it. It is interesting that at the end of a sentence, a contracted negation is allowed, but a contracted affirmative is not.

Comment: I actually meant contracted forms in general. Yes. The two examples of negated forms I gave are misleading. I modified the question.